# How do I stop a video play button in a hidden DIV from leaking into a visible DIV?

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari, shadow-dom

I’m working on a page with 4 content DIVs, 3 of which are hidden at any given time from the viewer, depending on which DIV link the viewer clicks on. One of these DIVs (#videos-and-more) will have one or more embedded videos on it. The page functions properly in desktop Firefox, Chrome and Safari. On mobile Safari there’s a baffling problem, in which the video play button -- and only the video play button -- shows up in all DIVs, whether they’re hidden or not.

html:

```
<div id="videos-and-more”>
<div class="videos-and-more-page">
<div class="video-wrapper1">
<video poster="ghost-venture-crew-zondra-mae-stanley-hotel.jpg" width="710" height="399" controls="auto">
<source src="ghost-venture-crew-zondra-stanley-hotel-hauntedhousesdotcom.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="ghost-venture-crew-zondra-stanley-hotel-hauntedhousesdotcom.ogg" type="video/ogg">
<source src="ghost-venture-crew-zondra-stanley-hotel-hauntedhousesdotcom.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#videos-and-more {visibility: hidden}
#videos-and-more:target {visibility: visible}

.videos-and-more-page {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
width: 800px;
margin: 20px auto;
top:250px;
z-index: 50;}

#gallery {visibility: hidden}
#gallery:target {visibility: visible}

.gallery-page {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
width: 800px;
margin: 20px auto;
top:250px;
z-index: 40;}

#full-story {visibility: hidden;}
#full-story:target {visibility: visible;}

.full-story-page {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
width: 800px;
margin: 20px auto;
top:250px;
z-index: 30;}

#quick-visit {visibility: hidden;}
#quick-visit:target {visibility: visible;}

.quick-visit-page {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
width: 800px;
margin: 20px auto;
top:250px;
z-index: 20;}
```

---

To see how the problem looks on my iPhone 4S, see the picture link.

--Thanks very much.

[HauntedHouses test page](http://hauntedhouses.com/states/co/stanley-hotel-test.htm#quick-visit)
[Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMIE1.jpg)

Comment: have you reproduced this using mobile emulation on your desktop browser?  If so you could try the inspector window to figure out why its showing.

Comment: No, I haven’t done that. Do you have any recommendations? What’s a good tool in your experience? Desktop Safari has a mobile display mode but it’s terrible.

Comment: The Chrome browser does a pretty good job of emulating mobile devices.  You can also connect your iphone to your desktop/laptop and debug your website via safari on your iphone.   Here's an article on how to set it up: https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/02/remote-debugging-ios-safari-on-os-x-windows-and-linux/